# XmlDocument SelectNodes: find an element by an attribute value only

Tags: c#-4.0, xpath, xmldocument

I want to add a child node to an element in XmlDocument. For the life of me I can't seem to find a way to all the elements where an attribute with a known value exists **without knowing the name of the element**.

However I can't get the xpath working.

```
doc.SelectNodes(/XXXXXX[@Name='the_value_I_want'])
```

What goes in XXXX please?

I'm more than happy to switch this function Linq2Xml if it's easier.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
doc.SelectNodes("//node()[@Name='the_value_I_want']")
```

or just

```
doc.SelectNodes("//[@Name='the_value_I_want']")
```

Answer (score 3):

Just use `*`

```
doc.SelectNodes(/*[@Name='the_value_I_want'])
```

OR

```
doc.SelectNodes(//*[@Name='the_value_I_want'])
```

Comment: Sorry this didn't return any nodes for me - I created a small test doc and @Pol's answer worked.